# How to stop next ajax request until current one get completed?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

Hi In my project I have input text box like following, where on "keyup" event I am making a call to managed bean where I perform searching operation in a arraylist.

That arraylist I show in p:dataTable which is named as userDataTable

My Code for xhtml

```
<p:inputText id="searchText" binding="#{searchText}"
            value="#{userData.searchReq}" autocomplete="off">
    <p:ajax listener="#{userManagement.userTable.searchListener}"
        event="keyup" update="userDataTable/>
</p:inputText>
```

This basically gives user to perform filtering on table when he types in inputText. But problem is user can type very fast. I want to stop next ajax call until current ajax call completed. How I can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using Primefaces, you can use the [AutoComplete](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autocompleteHome.jsf) component to perform exactly what you're ttrying to do. The first example shows a basic autocomplete functionality using arraylists.... you may refer that.

Autocomplete also has the feature of delaying your hit to the server to compensate for fast typing - the `queryDelay` attribute. Refer to the [User Guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation) for complete details.

Comment: Hi but queryDelay will slow my filter since I have to wait. I would like to have my ajax calls as I have mentioned above, I mean next ajax call should not be made until previous one has completed. In this way I dont have to wait and it can be more fast.

Comment: In that case don't set a delay. The results will be that of the most recent request that reaches. Since you're using a plain ArrayList, you won't see a difference. But in live sites, a delay is necessary to prevent too many database calls.